# Autogenerated Swift Extension functions with Enum Parameters

Tags: swift

I have a Swift 3.1 NSString Extension that looks like this:

```
enum MLCCapitalization : Int {
    case upperCase
    case lowerCase
    case na 
}

extension NSString {

    func MLC_stringByCapitalizingFirstLetterWithCapitalization(_ capitalization: MLCCapitalization, locale: Locale) -> NSString {
        let firstWordRange = rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.letters)
        guard firstWordRange.location != NSNotFound && capitalization != .na else {
            return self
        }

        let firstLetterRange = NSMakeRange(firstWordRange.location, 1)
        var firstLetter = substring(with: firstLetterRange)

        switch capitalization {
        case .upperCase:
            firstLetter = firstLetter.uppercased(with: locale)
        case .lowerCase:
            firstLetter = firstLetter.lowercased(with: locale)
        case .na:
            break
        }

        return replacingCharacters(in: firstLetterRange, with: firstLetter) as NSString
   }
}
```

I'm trying to call this from Objective-C, However this function is not being autogenerated in my projectname-Swift.h header file. It looks like this

```
@interface NSString (SWIFT_EXTENSION(ProjectName))
@end
```

It appears as though the enum parameter in this extension function is causing the problem (when I change it to an Int, it gets generated.) This worked fine in Swift 3.0. What am I missing?

Comment: If you want to expose something to Obj-C, you should mark it as `@objc` ;)

Comment: Uhmmm ... this is an extension of a system class, not my own class. And marking this extension public does not help.

Comment: Yes, but because `MLCCapitalization` isn't marked as `@objc`, your method isn't inferred to be `@objc`. You should mark *both* `MLCCapitalization` and the method as `@objc` (`public` is irrelevant), especially given the fact that methods added to `NSObject` derived classes will no longer be by default exposed to Obj-C in Swift 4.

Comment: Ahh yes, I see. I marked both the enum and function with @objc and it now appears in my Projectname-Swift.h file. Thanks for that. Now I need to figure out how to access this enum in my Objective-C code, especially since I use it in my .h files.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer here is to remove the enum from my Swift extension file and put it in an Objective-C header file. This objc header file can be included in the bridging header file so that it is also available to Swift. Doing what @Hamish suggested would have worked if I didn't need to use the enum in some of my Objective-C header files. Without the enum in the Swift extension file, there is no need to mark the functions with @objc. Thanks to @Hamish for pointing me in the right direction.